# Promise in javascript, function does not get executed after using $q.defer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

EDIT : i get an error like this when i last checked in browser console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined

I need to call one $http request which gives the token that can be used to call another $http request and finally the required response.
Hence i am using promises to make it work synchronously.However the function does not get executed after the `$q.defer()` function
Following is my code:

```
 $scope.firstTimeAuth = function($q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var ref = window.open('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write &approval_prompt=force&response_type=code&access_type=offline', '_blank', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

        if((event.url).startsWith("http://localhost/callback")) {
            requestToken = (event.url).split("code=")[1];

            $http({
                method: "post", url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                data: "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback" + "&grant_type=authorization_code" + "&code=" + requestToken
              })
              .success(function(data) {
                      defer.resolve(true);
                      accessToken = data.access_token;
                      refreshToken = data.refresh_token;
                      alert("firstTimeAuth success");

                      if(typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
                          localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",refreshToken);
                          alert(localStorage.getItem("refreshToken"));
                      } else {
                          alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
                      }

                      //functions here
                  })
               .error(function(data, status) {
                      alert("ERROR: " + data);
                      defer.resolve(true);
                  });
              ref.close();
          }
      });
     return deferred.promise;
  }
```

> This is my second function

```
$scope.getAcessToken = function($q)
  {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    alert("inside getAcessToken function");
    refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");

    if(refreshToken)
    {
      $http({
            method: "post", url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            data: "client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&grant_type=refresh_token" + "&refresh_token="+ refreshToken + "&client_id=" + clientId
              })
      .success(function(data){
            accessToken = data.access_token;
            alert("getAcessToken success" + accessToken);
            deferred.resolve(true);
      })
      .error(function(data,status){
        alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(data) + status);
        deferred.resolve(true);
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $scope.firstTimeAuth();
    }
   return deferred.promise;
  }
```

> and i call them like this.

```
 alert("not installed");
      var lastSaved = $scope.getFirstEpochTime();


      //walkthroug
      //Registe



      $scope.firstTimeAuth().then(function(){
        alert("firstime done");
        $scope.getDataSets().then(function(){
          alert(" in the last block");/*
          $scope.handleResponse().then(function(){
            $scope.insert().then(function(){
                $scope.select();
              })
            alert("done in installed");
          })
        */})
      })
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the code. i am very new to this.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you injecting `$q` in your `controller` at first place.

```
angular.module('module.name').controller('ControllerName', 
        ['$scope', '$q', function ($scope, $q) {

}]);
```

I am not really getting why are you passing `$q` to your function, you don't need that to be. `$scope.firstTimeAuth = function($q) {`

Comment: yes i have inserted $q in the controller.. but that wasnt helping so ithought ill   call it in function argument.

Comment: @Shravan: You should not pass it as an argument to your function, remove it... and it should work.

Comment: yes i have removed it. and now i am not getting the error anymore.
However the functions are still not called in sync.. can u suggest anything.???
i can share the project with you.
i am really stuck in this problem for a couple of days now. :(

Answer (score 1):

By defining a parameter for a function, you're creating a local variable which hides anything with the same name in outer scope. In your case you're defining:

```
$scope.firstTimeAuth = function($q) {}
```

And then you're invoking it like `$scope.firstTimeAuth();` in many places. Since you don't pass anything, `$q` in the functions scope will be undefined. You should only inject it in the entire controller scope and remove such parameters specified in scope methods so that it doesn't hide the injected service.

Or if you must pass them around for some reason, do it properly.

Comment: yes i have tried removing the $q which i have called in the function.
however the functions are still not getting synced.
thanks for pointing out the problem. 
I realised it now that the local declaration was hiding the declarations in outer scope.

Comment: can u suggest anything.??? i can share the project with you. i am really stuck in this problem for a couple of days now. :(

Comment: @Shravan you might want to update the question and explain exactly what you're trying to do... You seems to have access token, refresh token, localStorage etc I'm not sure what exactly isn't working. You can return a promise from the success callbackback of  `then()` and the promise returned will resolve only after the promise returned from `.then()` in case if you didn't know.